# How to get X coordinate of a word inside a NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, cgfloat

I have a label with a sentence in it, that is one string. I need to get the x coordinate for a specific word in the string. So for example, if I have a sentence that says "The dog ran" inside of the sentence, I need to be able to find the x and y coordinates, as well as the width and height to place a UITextField over it. Here is my code so far:

```
- (void)insertTextFields:(NSString *)string inLabel:(UILabel *)label
{
    CGFloat stringWidth = [self getWidthOfString:string inLabel:label];
    CGFloat stringHeight = label.bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat stringYOrigin = label.bounds.origin.y;
    CGFloat stringXOrigin = [self getXOriginOfString:string fromString:label.text inLabel:label];
    CGRect textFieldRect = CGRectMake(stringXOrigin, stringYOrigin, stringWidth, stringHeight);
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:textFieldRect];
    [label addSubview:textField];
}


- (CGFloat)getWidthOfString:(NSString *)string inLabel:(UITextField *)label
{
    CGFloat maxWidth = CGRectGetMaxX(label.frame);
    CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithFont:label.font forWidth:maxWidth lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
    CGFloat width = stringSize.width;
    return width;
}

- (CGFloat)getXOriginOfString:(NSString *)string fromString:(NSString *)sentenceString inLabel:(UILabel *)label
{
    CGFloat maxWidth = CGRectGetMaxX(label.frame);
    CGSize sentenceStringSize = [sentenceString sizeWithFont:label.font forWidth:maxWidth lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithFont:label.font forWidth:maxWidth lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    //I have the width of both the individual word and the sentence
    //now I need to find the X coordinate for the individual word inside of the sentence string
    return xOrigin;
}
```

Could someone tell me what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the x position of the start of the word?  Just measure the string that precedes the word....

```
- (CGFloat)getXOriginOfString:(NSString *)string fromString:(NSString *)sentenceString inLabel:(UILabel *)label {

    CGFloat maxWidth = CGRectGetMaxX(label.frame);
    NSRange range = [sentenceString rangeOfString:string];
    NSString *prefix = [sentenceString substringToIndex:range.location];

    return [prefix sizeWithFont:label.font
                       forWidth:maxWidth
                  lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].width;
}
```

The end of the word will be this result + the `stringSize` in the code you posted.  Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Calculating glyph positions is a complex task. A typesetter might decide to place the start of the word at a different position when seeing the whole string. This approach might work in some situations but break in others.

Comment: I made some slight modifications to your code and it is working! Thanks fot the help.

Comment: Glad to hear.  What did you change?  ... so future readers can be helped.

Comment: NSString *prefix = [string substringToIndex:range.location]; - change here string to sentenceString cause your code is wrong now

Comment: @DmitriyKalachniuk - good catch.  Edited.  Thanks for improving it.

Comment: `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0 - Use `-boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`